# XMLHttpRequest как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, xhr

Нужна помощь по XHR (XMLHttpRequest).

Допустим, отправляю GET запрос на /msg.php. Оттуда получаю данные (сообщения) и  через `innerHTML` вывожу.
Запросы отправляются через `setInterval(message, 2000);`, то есть через каждые 2 сек.

Вот такой вопрос, как реализовать допустим так:

Идет GET на /msg.php, ждать 25 сек. есть ли ответ (или сообщение), и повторить заново.

Заметил, такой принцип работает в VK [(пример)](https://pp.userapi.com/c639826/v639826082/3ec5a/Li5veB5ch0w.jpg)

Comment: Это называется long polling. Юзайте лучше WebSocket.

Comment: Или чат Iframe 

Comment: Там никакой ajax не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Для этого есть таймаут. Я так понял, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.timeout = 25000; // Время в миллисекундах

xhr.ontimeout = function (evt) {
  // Таймаут. Здесь можно выполнить что-нибудь..
};
```

Вот можно на MDN почитать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout

Answer (score 1):

У вас ответ в самом вопросе

> Идет GET на /msg.php, ждать 25 сек.

Если совсем упростить пример для наглядности, то внутри `msg.php` пишите:

```
$end = time() + 25;
while (time() < $end) {
    // тут проверяем наличие новых сообщений и выполняем для них echo
    // echo '<script>msg("test!")</script>'
    sleep(1);
}
```

На клиенте в JS обрабатываете полученные вызовы `msg()` и перезапускаете весь процесс по новой каждые 30 сек. (таков исторически таймаут на соединение в старом добром IE и все придерживаются его).

Или просто подключите какой-нить [socket.io](https://socket.io/). В нём всё есть из коробки, кроссбраузерно, но написано на node.js.